# How do I delete a large block of text without counting the lines?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

In vim, I often need to delete, or yank/put large blocks of text.

I can count the lines of text and enter something like `50dd` to delete 50 lines.

But that's a bit of a pain. How can I delete this large block of text *without* having to know how many lines to delete in advance?

Comment: How do you know where the end is? If you can describe the end you can delete to that point. If you can describe how you can `move` to the end. Then deleting to the end is no different than moving to the end.

Comment: @Loki, moving to the end is usually just using page-down and the arrow keys until I reach there. It _may_ be the first or tenth blank line, it _may_ be the first closing brace. Bottom line is, it varies quite a bit.

Comment: also check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16407391/164835

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Go to the starting line of your block, and type <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (mark "a", though you can of course use *different* letters, and even *multiple* letters for different marks provided you can keep it straight in your head what each letter is a mark of).

Then go to the last line and enter <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (delete to mark "a") or <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (yank to mark "a") <sup>(a)</sup>.

That will delete/yank all lines from the current to the marked one (inclusive).

Then you can paste it somewhere else with the normal paste commands, such as <kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>P</kbd>.

It's also compatible with `vi` as well as `vim`, on the off chance that your environment is not blessed with the latter.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I also use this to save my place in the file if I have to go looking elsewhere for something like, for example, copy-pasting the definition of a function I want to call.

I simply mark the current line in the same way, <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, then wander off to find whatever you're looking for.

Then, once I've found it and copied it to a register, I just enter <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to go back to mark "a", the line I saved beforehand, where I can then paste it.

Comment: Might as well use visual mode for this, right?

Comment: That's _one_ way, jmc, but I'm not sure _standard_ vi has a visual mode.

Comment: — I definitely agree with you that this is a viable approach in vi. But as the question only mentions vim, it seems rather strange (incomplete) not to mention visual mode in your answer.

Comment: Since I moved from visual selection to marking and relative line numbers about a year ago I found that vi motion commands are much faster and efficient then visual selection. Even though the later is *easier* every time I hit the `v` key I ask myself do I really need it or is there a better motion way?

Comment: Yeah, in the same way it's interesting, @Sukima, that I feel more efficient the less I use the mouse, even in a GUI. I find myself being faster if I can stay on the keyboard.

Comment: If you're ever editing something with really long lines, the backtick version of this might come in very handy as well (which refers to the place withinin the line, rather than the whole line).

Comment: Hello, just wanted to let you know I came over here from Area 51 just to check things out. This question was the first I clicked on, and your answer the first I saw, and I learned something! And you're awesome for that.

Comment: `d` `'` `a` ... I Love Vim

Answer (score 78):

In Vim, use [visual line mode](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html):

1. Put your cursor on the top line of the block of text/code to remove
2. Press <kbd>V</kbd> (That's capital "V" : <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> )
3. Move your cursor down to the bottom of the block of text/code to remove
4. Press  <kbd>d</kbd>

For deleting large blocks of text this is preferred over simple visual mode because you don't need to worry about which column the cursor is at.

Comment: In step 3. you can move faster using object motions. For example can use `}` to select entire paragraph or `)` for sentences. There are more, you can read about them in `:h object-motions`

Comment: Also searching for a substring with `/something<CR>` is a very efficient method to reach to the end of your selection block

Comment: This is my preferred method. However alternatively without having to repeatedly press `j` to move the cursor down (step 3), you can type the line number followed by `G` to select until that line. Example: `V150Gd`

Answer (score 48):

You can easily delete large block of text if you know its structure.

- If it's a paragraph, use `d{` or `d}` or `dap` (or `3d{` for 3 paragraphs and so on).
- If it's within parenthesis, use `d%` or `dab` or `da(` or `da)`.
- If it's the text till end of the file, use `dG`
- If you know how it ends, use `d/` and type the ending text followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> (you can also use a regular expression, so the possibilities are endless).

Alternatively use visual line mode (`V`) and use motion keys to quickly select the text (e.g. by `{`) and remove it (`d` or `x`).

Or as Lie Ryan suggested, use `d/search-string/e`<kbd>Enter</kbd> to delete text from current cursor to searched string.

See: `:help d` and `:help motion` for more info.

Comment: There is also `d/search-string/e` to delete from current cursor to the end of the search string including the search string itself and `c/search-query` to get into insert mode after deletion. Using `d/` with `set incsearch` is a neat combination as it allows you to interactively figure out whether you are operating on the right text range, and help you know when to stop typing the search query to avoid typing more than is necessary.

Comment: I also find `d` with `a` (outer), or `i` (inner) and an object specifier very useful. Objects such as `w` for word, `p` for paragraph, `(` or `b` for `(...)`, `[` for `[...]`, `{` or `B` for `{...}` etc. [documentation for visual-operators](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-operators).

Comment: Note that `d%` works for block comments in code.

Answer (score 43):

You can [`:set relativenumber`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27relativenumber%27), so you don't have to count. ;)

Comment: Or `:set number`, and then use d35G to delete until line 35.

Comment: The numbers.vim plugin recommended in [ediblemanager's answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/1959/51) is like `relativenumber`, but better :-)

Answer (score 24):

You can use motions and/or text objects. For instance, you can delete everything from the cursor to the next blank line with `d}`. If the cursor is inside a paragraph, the paragraph may be deleted with `dip` or `dap`. If the cursor is within a HTML tag, you can delete it with `dit` or `dat`.

Good mnemonics for these are "**d**elete **i**nside" and "**d**elete **a**round" (paragraph / tag / parenthesis).

Answer (score 16):

I usually do

```
:<start>,<end>d
```

which will delete every line between the start and end line numbers provided (including the given lines).

Note that both `start` and `end` can be absolute line numbers, patterns, or offsets from another position.

Also see doubleDown's comment about viewing Vim's *range* documentation, it has some useful tips.

**Example:**

Say you have the following file:

```
1. The quick brown
2. fox jumps
3. over the
4. lazy dog.
```

Then by using the command `:2,3d` or `:/fox/,/over/d` or `:/quick/+1,/lazy/-1` or `:+1,+2d` if you're on the first line or `:-1,.d` if you're on the third line, you end up with:

```
1. The quick brown
4. lazy dog.
```

Comment: But this means you still need to count the lines? Or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: You don't need to count the lines, but you do need to know the line numbers.

Comment: First do `:set ruler`, then go to the top & bottom of the text to find `start` and `end` line numbers, then do `:<start>,<end>d`

Comment: or `:set number` so that you can see all the line numbers.  `:set ruler` is superior because you can just leave that on (even set in your vimrc) with minimal visual intrusion, though.  I just thought it would be good to mention `:set number` in case anyone was unaware.  Very useful in screen sharing, presentations, etc to make it easy for people to refer to specific lines.

Comment: You could also use relative line numbers `:+12,+24d`

Comment: Actually, you can use a pair of line numbers, a pair of patterns, or mixed pair for `<start>` and `<end>` for this. For reference, see `:h [range]`. So it's actually quite a bit more flexible than you made it out to be.

Answer (score 6):

If it is delimited blocks (eg: code or XML/HTML tags) that you're dealing with, you can position the cursor at the start of the block and use the visual mode along with `%` to quickly select entire blocks of code and then hit `d` to delete them.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `dap` to delete a paragraph, `da(`, `da{`, `da[`, to delete blocks delimeted by parentheses, braces, or square brackets. For html there is `dat`, which deletes a tag, and `da'` and `da"` delete strings. There is also the `dip`, `di(`, etc variants, that will delete everything inside the delimiters, but leave the delimiters intact. Alternatively, you can use `vap` (resp `vip`) to select all (resp inner) paragraph. (And so there is `va(` and `vi(`.) Further there is `cap` and `cip` (or `ca(` and `ci(`) to delete and go to insert mode (i.e., "change"). And `yap` to yank

Comment: I think some of the bindings @jmc described in his earlier comment are from the surround.vim plugin by Tim Pope. It's a great plugin that I'd recommend installing, but it does mean these bindings aren't part of the default vim installation.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from all the other good advice I'm adding <kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for deleting everything from the current cursor position to the last visible line on the screen. Repeating the command will get you down relatively fast.

Answer (score 5):

The [numbers.vim](http://myusuf3.github.io/numbers.vim/) plugin is very useful for this. It's an enhanced way to precede each line with a line number. Like `'number'` and `'relativenumber'`, both roled into one!

It's enabled by default after installation, you also want to add `set number` to your vimrc if you haven't got it already, since it behaves in strange ways if you don't have it.

In *normal mode* it looks similar to `:set relativenumber`:

```
  3 call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
  2 
  1 Plug 'myusuf3/numbers.vim'
7   set number█
  1 
  2 " Add indentation 'guidelines' (:IndentLinesToggle or <F11>)
  3 Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
```

It shows you relative line numbers, **except** for the line where the cursor is on, where it shows the absolute line number (7 in this case).

If we then switch to *insert mode*, it will behave as if `number` was set by always showing absolute line numbers:

```
  4 call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
  5 
  6 Plug 'myusuf3/numbers.vim'
  7 set number█
  8   
  9 " Add indentation 'guidelines' (:IndentLinesToggle or <F11>)
 10 Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
```

There are some more options and a few commands (check the homepage), but the defaults should work for most people.

Comment: At first I thought this answer was a bit off topic but then I installed the plugin and I have to say it's a game changer for me. I used to swap manually and the extra mental step meant that I shyed away from using those motions. Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like something that one InsertEnter/InsertLeave autocmd to toggle relative line numbering could do. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm VERY late to the party but @Ben is right, this is just a couple autocommand lines. For example, in my vimrc I have `set number`, `set relativenumber` then `autocmd InsertEnter * :set norelativenumber` and `autocmd InsertLeave * :set relativenumber`

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is if you are trying to delete to a specific pattern, you can simply type <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>`delim`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the normal procedure of entering <kbd>d</kbd> plus a motion (as already explained in the other answers). The EasyMotion plugin, provides new motions you can use that could solve your problem in a quick and easy way.

Say you want to to delete from the current cursor position to the end of any given word on the screen, the motion keys would be <kbd>`<Leader>`</kbd><kbd>`<Leader>`</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> (akin to the normal `e` motion). Then type the highlighted letter(s) that appear at the end of the word in question. There is also a line motion so you can delete the current line down to the line in question with <kbd>`<Leader>`</kbd><kbd>`<Leader>`</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>.

I have my `<Leader>` key set to <kbd>,</kbd>. So, the full command is <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>`<Leader>`</kbd><kbd>`<Leader>`</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>{highlighted letter(s)}.

From `:help easymotion`:

> EasyMotion provides a much simpler way to use some motions in vim. It takes
>   the `<number>` out of `<number>`w or `<number>`f`{char}` by highlighting all possible 
>   choices and allowing you to press one key to jump directly to the target.
>
> When one of the available motions is triggered, all visible text preceding or
>   following the cursor is faded, and motion targets are highlighted.

Edit:

EasyMotion's [github repository](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) is at https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion.

This [reddit about people using easymotion](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1yfzg2/does_anyone_actually_use_easymotion/) might be a fun read.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution that can solve your problem.

Place your cursor at the begining of the text block you want to remove, and do `d50gg`.

This will delete all the lines from your current position to the 50th line of your text.

e.q: if your cursor is at line **46**, `d50gg` will delete **4** lines.

Comment: I'd suggest using `G` instead of gg as it also works in vi, and of course `:set number` is always useful for finding what line number the line you want to go to is.

Comment: The whole point of this question is that you don't know how many lines you want to remove.

Comment: 200_success, you don't have to know how many lines you want to remove with the answer i posted. All you have to know is "to which line do you want to remove"

Answer (score 1):

Use visual mode with line highlighting.

1. Put your cursor on the top line of the block of text/code to remove
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>
3. Move your cursor down to the bottom of the block of text/code to remove
4. Press  <kbd>d</kbd>

I prefer this method for deleting blocks of code because it deletes whole lines compared to simply using visual mode where you have to position the cursor in the right column to delete what you want.

Comment: You essentially repeat the answer by @200_success.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to have `relativenumber` on all the time, so I configured my Vim to enable it only when I am in Visual Mode:

```
" Entering Visual mode
nnoremap <silent>     v :set relativenumber cursorcolumn<CR>v
nnoremap <silent> <C-q> :set relativenumber cursorcolumn<CR><C-q>
nnoremap <silent>    gv :set relativenumber cursorcolumn<CR>gv
nnoremap <silent>     V :set relativenumber<CR>V

" When finished
augroup ClearCursorColumnAndLine
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorHold * set norelativenumber nocursorcolumn nocursorline
augroup END
```

This makes your task easy:

```
V49jd
```

because after hitting <kbd>V</kbd> you can see how far away the target line is.

This may prove annoying in the long run (the text shifts right and left when relativenumber is enabled/disabled), but so far I am quite enjoying it.

Comment: I think you use `v<Esc>d50j`?

Comment: Thanks, I had indeed written it incorrectly.  Actually I start with `V` if I know I will be doing a line-wise operation, and then I can leave the `d` until last, for greater confidence.

Comment: My answer appears to be a poor man's approximation of the [numbers.vim](http://myusuf3.github.io/numbers.vim/) plugin offered in another answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What worked great for me with `vi`:

1. `:set number` to view the number of the line until  where I wanted to delete;

   ```
   +1289 idle 
   +1289 idle 
   +1290 # <- I want to delete until here
   +1291 if [[ ! -z "$SFIN" ]]
   ```
2. Go back to the line where deletion had to start
3. Used deletion from current line, in normal mode> `d1290G`

Answer (score 1):

You could also search for your text. For e.g. start your cursor where you want to delete. Then, enter visual mode:

```
Shift + V
```

Now, search for whatever phrase you want to end at. For example, if you want to end at the next end parentheses:

```
/)
```

Hit enter and the corresponding section will be highlighted. You can cycle through search results by hitting `n`. Once the relevant section is highlighted, you can easily delete the selection now:

```
d
```