# Can relative number be changed so that current line is 1?

Tags: line-numbers

I *knew* this site would teach me more about my beloved `vim` :-) In posting a question/answer on [how to delete large blocks without having to count lines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/how-do-i-delete-a-large-block-of-text-without-counting-the-lines), one of the answers taught me something I didn't know, that being relative line numbers along the lines of:

```
  2 This is line 1
  1 This is line 2
3   This is line 3, the current line.
  1 This is line 4.
  2 Line 5.
  3 Line 6.
```

Now, if you wanted to delete lines 3, 4 and 5, you can simply add one to the relative line number (2) and use that to set the count, the command being `3dd`.

However, adding one seems a bit obscure so I was wondering if you could configure the line numbers in relative mode to be more like this:

```
  2 This is line 1
  1 This is line 2
3 1 This is line 3, the current line.
  2 This is line 4.
  3 Line 5.
  4 Line 6.
```

That way you could simply transcribe the number into the command without having to think about it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't do that.  A numbering system that goes from -1 to +1 without a zero in between is just asking for trouble.

As an alternative habit, I suggest <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> — "delete this line and the next two lines".  That works both ways: <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> deletes upward.

A long-winded ex command version of that would be `:+2d`.

Comment: Accepting for the `d2j` which solves the problem.

Comment: What's the problem with *line numbers* going from -1 to +1? I can see how it could cause you trouble in mathematics, but in line numbers?

Comment: @Jerry The asymmetry between the upward and downward numbering schemes would be harmful, for example. It would make my suggested `d2j` vs. `d2k` confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe: `d<number><CR>`