# Copy text based on delimiting strings

Tags: search, cut-copy-paste

I see how to copy text in vim using visual mode, arrow keys, <kbd>y</kbd> to yank, and <kbd>p</kbd> to paste. I also see how to find a given starting string using back slash.

However, I'd appreciate knowing how to copy all the text from a given start phrase (such as `To list all available commands enter "/?"`) to a given stop phrase (such as `Enter chat message or link here`).

I'd normally just use arrow keys, but for my application, the number of lines in-between the start and stop phrases may vary, so I'd like one script to work in all cases.

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. Does the solution also work in vimium? I asked the question on this site because practically everything that works for vim also works for vimium, but my actual application uses vimium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the idea of using marks is indeed a good approach. Here is a function to add to your `.vimrc` to ease the process:

```
function! SelectDelimitations(start, end)
    " Set start mark
    call search(a:start)
    normal! ma
    " Set end mark at the end of the match
    call search(a:end, "e")
    normal! mb

    " Go to start mark and select the text
    normal! `a
    normal! v`b
endfunction
```

You can then use the function this way:

```
:call SelectDelimitation("Start pattern", "end pattern")
```

This will select the text between the patterns.

An interesting point in this function is that the text is selected character wise thanks to the backtick used in the `normal` command and the search flag `e` used to go to the end of the second pattern.

Answer (score 1):

After some googling (mainly thanks to [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/how-do-i-delete-a-large-block-of-text-without-counting-the-lines?rq=1)), I seem to have come up with a solution. The crucial idea is to use marks.

First, search for the starting phrase using the back slash command. Call this mark `a` by typing <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

Next, search for the closing phrase using the back slash command again. Finally, once the cursor is at this position, type <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (to yank to mark `a`).