# Uncomment multiple lines

Tags: normal-mode, comments

In vim I can use for instance <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to go 10 lines down. And I can use `.` to repeat the last deletion.

Now, in bash script I have many commented lines like this:

```
# ...
# ...
# ...
# ...
# ...
# ...
# ...
# ...
# ...
etc...
```

Say, there are 52 such lines. Is there a way to combine moving `52j` and repeating the deletion of the `#` via `x` and delete 52 lines at once?

Comment: You could try [block deletion](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/1917/1405) or some [plugin specific for comments](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/).

Comment: I would go with a `:s` command

Comment: When on the first "#", do ``^v54jx`` (ctrl+v then 54jx), i.e. make a visual block on current column on all 54 lanes and delete it. Similarly, you can revert this with ``^v54I#<ESC>`` (or even ``gvI#<ESC>`` [gv = reopen previous visual mode])

Answer (score 11):

I do approve @mMontu comment suggesting to use a comment plugin ([vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/) is an option but [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) has my preference over vim-commentary).

But you could do it in other ways:

- First if all your `#` are aligned on the same column you can block select them with <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> and then delete your selection with <kbd>x</kbd>.
- If they are not aligned you could use a macro:

  ```
  qq^xjq

  qq        Record a macro in the register q
  ^         Go to beginning of line
  x         Suppress the first character
  j         Go one line down
  q         Stop recording
  ```

  You can then repeat your macro as many time as necessary with <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>
- And with NERDCommenter:

  - Select your 52 lines with <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>52</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>
  - Use the NERDCommenter mapping to uncomment your lines: <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>

For more details:

- [`:h blockwise-visual`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#blockwise%2Dvisual)
- [`:h recording`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#recording)

Comment: I know it's already linked in the comment, but maybe a link to vim-commentary would be nice? I'd add it myself but it seems rude!

Comment: @Rich I didn't add it because it is pretty easy to find and has already been referenced often on this site but it is now corrected. Also I really don't mind user editing my answer even with minor correction (when they are meaningful) that's how community driven site should work ;-)

Comment: Okay, I'll bear that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 10):

I like the approaches statox suggested. Here's another one:

```
52:norm x
```

This only works if the `#` is the first character on each line. Otherwise, I would do

```
52:s/#
```

These two work very similarly. Essentially, what `<count>:` is doing, is setting up a range so that the next ex command is applied to the next `<count>` lines. `norm x` means

> Press 'x' as if it was in normal mode

which would obviously remove the first character on that line.

`s/#` is just shorthand for `:substitute/#//` which will remove the first `#` character on each line.

Answer (score 0):

#### Having a space with the commenting character?

**Assumptions** : *commented lines are **continuous** and commenting character (<kbd>#</kbd> in your case) is at beginning of all those lines.*

1. Come to the beginning of the first commented line.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>  *switches to **visual-block mode***.
3. Type <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>  ***selects** beginning of next 52 lines*.
4. Use <kbd>h</kbd> / <kbd>l</kbd> or <kbd>◁</kbd> / <kbd>▷</kbd> respectively  ***selecting** multiple columns*.
5. Press <kbd>x</kbd>  ***deletes** the selection*.
6. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>  *back to **normal mode***.

**References**: [What's a quick way to comment/uncomment lines in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1676632/10204932)

Namaste

Comment: Ix in visual block mode just inserts and x at the beginning of all lines in the selection. Perhaps you meant to suggest typing x or d in visual block mode?

Comment: Edited my answer, Thank You @D.BenKnoble